# How to scrapy dynamic variable from JavaScript without rendering it?

Tags: javascript, python, scrapy

I used python to scrapy the web http://www.nowgoal.id/nba.htm, however the data I needed   about games is filled by the script http://www.nowgoal.id/data/nba.js. Then，I go to the js web and find the data was stored in a dynamic variable named 'matchdata'. 
[image]

Running the 'matchdata' in the concole of chrome DevTools, we can see variable 'matchdata' is a list of array. Each array contains the information of a game, as the pic show.
[image]

I know some tools can render the javascript, like scrayjs/PhantomJS, but they spend a lot of time. I wonder is there some ways can directly get the content of variable 'matchdata'.

Answer (score 1):

You can't unless the JS variable has a static value, in which case you'd be able to simply extract it from the source code.

But in your case, there seems to be couple of XHR calls involved (check Developer tools and Network tab), like these two:

```
http://www.nowgoal.id/NBA/en.xml?t=1508135111000
http://www.nowgoal.id/NBA/nbaGoal3.xml?1508135112000
```

Does any of these provide you with the data you need? If so, simply use them as your `start_urls` and extract the data from resulting XML.

Comment: Thanks！Unfortunately, the apis don't contain what I need.